# How to create an infinite loop by condition in imacros?

Tags: javascript, imacros

If the 1.txt file appears in the imacros folder, then continue.

```css
SET !DATASOURCE C:\1.txt
SET !DATASOURCE {{!LOOP}}
```

Comment: There is a mistake somewhere.

Comment: `while(0)` will never run to begin with. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: 1. Run the macro
2. If in the file C: //1.txt in the first line there is 1
3. We continue the work of the macro

Comment: Thanks for answers.